# When referring to a numbered equation, do I capitalise “equation”?

Tags: reference-request, notation, article-writing

Suppose, I wrote an following equation:

> $$f(x)=x^2\tag1$$

NOw I want to refer to it later in my work. Which of the following do I write?

> Using Equation (1) we can see that $f(x)$ is an even function.
>
> Using equation (1) we can see that $f(x)$ is an even function.

Does referring to a specific equation needs a capital *E* or not?

Comment: Personally, it'd be more appropriate to capitalize it since Equation (1) is referred to as a proper noun (much like Theorem 3.14). Like, you gave it a name.

Comment: Whatever you do, please do not parenthesise 1 in the reference, i.e., write “Equation 1” instead of “Equation (1)”. The parentheses serve to avoid confusing the number with a part of the equation when labelling it, they are not part of the numbering system, serve no purpose whatsoever, and just hinder readability.

Comment: Related questions on [english.se]: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28020/42471), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28373/42471), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/189196/42471).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not specific to mathematical writing, but is about English capitalisation in general. The same problem occurs with figures, tables, chapters, etc.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft [This answer, in particular, is spot on.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189199)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a matter of style, and I don't think there is a "right" or "wrong" here, but I think it is rare to see "equation" capitalized. Even referring to a named equation, it's usually "Laplace's equation" rather than "Laplace's Equation".

Comment: Maybe I'm splitting hairs, but possessive proper pronouns are not usually capitalized, like "Bill Clinton's wife is Hillary Clinton". Even if "Clinton's wife" refers to a proper noun Hillary, it's not capitalized.

Comment: There are no pronouns here.  "Clinton's wife" or "Clinton's equation" are generally not capitalized, but "Clinton's Lemma" or "Clinton's Theorem" might be.
AFAIK Clinton has not produced any lemmas or theorems, but maybe some propositions...

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant nouns, like "Clinton's theorem" and "my bad".

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking: By default, as you say, nouns in possessive phrases like *Clinton’s dog* aren’t capitalised.  But there’s a specific convention in technical writing to capitalise certain nouns in certain contexts: “Chapter 1”, “Section 5.3”, “Theorem 12.1” are almost always capitalised (but “in the next section…” is not); “Figure 4”, “Equation 7”, “Cantor’s Theorem”, “Laplace’s Equation” are sometimes capitalised but not as often as the former group.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a matter of style, not mathematics. When I write I refer to "the previous equation" but to "Equation (1)" since the former is a common noun while the latter is a proper noun.